# How to copy/download folder from server to local machine using ssh

Tags: ssh, server, copy, scp

There is folder into my server name files and it path become:

```
          user@mydomain.com:/var/www/temp/files
```

I want to copy files folder into my local machine

I am trying following command but it does not work at the end it says connection timeout

```
   scp -r shhu@imagesdb.u-blox.com:/var/www/temp/files Users/shhu/files  // destination
```

I want to copy into Users/shhu/files
Can anyone please help me on this?
Thankyou in advance

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su]. When you do, please include the exact error message that you're getting from `scp`. Don't paraphrase it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can connect to server from local machine.
Make sure that sshserver is running and also check the firewall of servers.